# Manually adding a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install the mechanize gem that is supposed to work with 1.9 from here: http://github.com/kemiller/mechanize but I do not know how to add it manually.

I am using Windows, I could just copy the folder to the gems directory, but how do I initialize it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. `gem install mechanize` doesn't work? It produces version 0.9.3 for me, which matches the gemspec of the library you linked to.

EDIT: you're on 1.9. I knew that. Disregard my hasty post, not familiar enough with Windows to offer any help on building the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the bundler gem using the command `gem install bundler`. This will create a file called `Gemfile` in your project directory where you can put your dependencies for the specific project that you are working on. In the Gemfile, you will need to specify `gem mechanize`. If you want a specific version include `~> VERSION` after. After, run the command `bundle install`. This will install the gem you want and use it in your project.